# Datatables Jquery - No matching records found

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have Jquery Datatables server side and When i navigate to my page to see results in Datatables it displays "No matching records found" and than i debugged my code i can see its retrieve currect data and i also check Response in browser it is also retrieve data.

Json Response:

```
{"data":
[{"Kundenavn":"test 1"},
{"Kundenavn":"test 2"},
{"Kundenavn":"test 3"}]
,"draw":"1","recordsTotal":567,"recordsFiltered":567}
```

JavaScript:

```
<table id="OrdrerList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Kundenavn</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

$('#OrdrerList').DataTable({

 "processing": true,
 "serverSide": true,

    ajax:{
        url: '@Url.Action("GetClosedRMA", "User")',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataSrc: ''

        },
    columns: [

        { data: "Kundenavn" }
   ]
});
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetClosedRMA()
{
    //Server side Parameters

    int start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]);
    int length = Convert.ToInt32(Request["length"]);
    string searchValue = Request["search[value]"];
    string sortColumnName = Request["columns["+ Request["order[0][colmun]"]+ "][name]"];
    string sortDirection = Request["order[0][dir]"];

    List<RMAclosedCase> rmalist = new List<RMAclosedCase>();
    using (Namespace db = new Namespace())
    {
       rmalist = (from RH in db.RMA_History
                   join RS in db.RMAStatus on RH.StatusID equals RS.ID
                   where RH.SagesType == "LUK"
                   select new RMAclosedCase
                   {
                       Kundenavn = RH.Kundenavn

                   }).ToList();

       int totalrows = rmalist.Count();
            //Filter
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
            {
                rmalist = rmalist.Where(x => x.Kundenavn.ToLower().Contains(searchValue.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
       int totalrowsefterfiltering = rmalist.Count();

        //Paging
        rmalist = rmalist.Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();

        return Json(new {data= rmalist,draw = Request["draw"], recordsTotal = totalrows,recordsFiltered = totalrowsefterfiltering },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

What did i wrong?! :) Can anyone please help me or point me into right direction! :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get data as dataset, then set datatable and set dataset as data.

```
  $('#example').DataTable({
                     select: {
                            style: 'multi'
                        },
                        data: dataSet,
                        columns: [
                            { title: "Kundenavn" } 
                        ],
                        paging: false,
                        searching: false,
                        destroy: true,

                    });
```

Answer (score 3):

simply remove
`dataSrc:""`
from your ajax request. this worked for me in similar situation.

Comment: @AbdulSaleem After removing dataSrc parameter, i'm getting "DataTables warning: table id=tbTest- Requested unknown parameter" error,

Comment: @Light you see that error means, you have successfully received the data. Now you are facing next issue. Unknown parameter issue comes when you ask for some column and that column doesn't exist in your received data

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your column names have the same names as the fields from the database.
Note: Datatable capitalizes the first letter of each column name. your HTML column names should be lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The data you want to display is nested in the `data` property of your JSON. Thus, to make it work, you need to set `dataSrc: 'data'` as explained in the official documentation:

https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Data-array-location and
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc#Examples

Removing `dataSrc:""` as suggested in another answer works because `dataSrc: 'data'` is the default.